# MongoDB - How to define arrays key?

Tags: mongodb

**I have this query in MongoDB -**

```
db.getCollection('A91282774').update({"_id":"5704fd6eb23eec37168b4567"}, 
{'$addToSet':
    {'AutoFix':
        {
            'Kieron': []
        }
    }
}, 
{"upsert":"true"})
```

**The result I get is**

[image]

When what I want is 'Kieron' to be in the place of the '0' but the '0' isn't an array just a value instead.

**So it will look like this -**

```
"AutoFix" : {
    "K" : [ 
        "mabel__chan", 
        "mabel chan"
    ],
    "B" : [ 
        "kieron br"
    ],
    "C" : [ 
        "a br", 
        "a"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't this work?

db.A91282774.update({"_id":"5704fd6eb23eec37168b4567"},{$push:{'autofix.Keiron':"kb"}},{"upsert":"true"})

you will have to use autofix.keiron. if more than one keiron, you'll need $elemmatch to find the one you wish to update. and then parth of the query would change to autofix.$.keiron

Comment: No I'm looking for 'Kieron' to be the array with values 'KB, Kier' in it